# Possibly alternative definition of Ramsey numbers?

Tags: combinatorics, ramsey-theory

[On this presentation](https://youtu.be/F1J491z0mG0), the definition of Ramsey numbers seems to vary from the very understandable [Wikipedia explanation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ramsey%27s_theorem) for $2$-colorability of the edges of a complete graph resulting in red or blue cliques of a certain size.

Instead, they are defined as follows:

> $r_k(n)$ is the minimal $N$ such that every $2$-coloring of the $k$-sets of an $N$-set contains a monochromatic $n$-set.

I have no idea what $k$-set they are referring to. It is possible that the choice of the letter $k$ is due to the nomenclature for complete graphs as $K_n$ (for $n$ vertices).

There is little doubt that the definition given is equivalent, but how is reconciles with the usual $R(r,s)$ for red clique on $r$ vertices or a blue clique on $s$ vertices?

Comment: A complete graph on $N$ nodes can be thought of as the set of all $2$-sets of nodes - that is, subsets of the set of nodes of size $2.$  This generalizes that idea.

Comment: The relation is $r_2(n)=R(n,n).$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Jacob is talking about hypergraphs, where instead of edges (connecting two vertices) we have "hyperedges" connecting $k$ vertices simultaneously.  The number $r_2(n)$ (in his notation) is equal to $R(n, n)$ (in your other notation).

Comment: So the symmetry in the cliques ($(n,n)$) is assumed throughout?

Comment: I have not watched the whole video, but that's certainly what it sounds like at the beginning.

Comment: Still hasn't sunk in... Sorry... Would the subindex in $r_{2}(n)$ indicate that edges connect $2$ vertices, whereas if instead of edges one wanted to indicate hyperedges connecting $k$ vertices, the expression would be $r_k(n)$?

Comment: @JAP Yes, exactly.